# A science fiction story about a headdress that allows one human to control and experience another human's body

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this story many years ago and now can't remeber who wrote it or even what it was called. The story was about a group of elite humans who had access to a headdress that allowed them to control another human, even if they were thousands of miles away.  They could use this ability to commit crimes, etc.

I think the cover may have been yellow like those published by Gollancz.

Comment: Oooh that's totally a Pohl novel, lemme see.. No wait maybe it isn't, but I've totally read it. Grrr.

Comment: Yes I though that too but I just can't find it

Comment: Verbal confirmation received, closing.

Comment: see high-detail Q&A for this story at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227214/novel-where-a-mind-control-device-is-used-to-commit-murders

Answer (score 9):

Aha! Is it [A Plague of Pythons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Plague_of_Pythons), AKA Demon in the Skull, by Frederik Pohl? ([here's](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/images/0879979399/ref=dp_image_0?ie=UTF8&n=283155&s=books) a different cover on Amazon). According to an Amazon review, this is the back cover quote:

> Something had seized his mind, something that rode his body like a speed-maniac would drive a stolen car - for he had committed atrocities against his friends and neighbors, he had done unspeakable things - and yet his own conscious mind had only stood aside and watched in horror. For a demonic intelligence had taken over inside his skull and left him a helpless observer.

The Wikipedia summary also indicates that the control is performed by means of headdresses, and that some "elite humans" are doing it.

Comment: Fanatstic thanks that is it